# How can I print a list in columns?

Tags: html, css, list

I have a long list, made of strings of various sizes. Right now it prints like this:

```
item    longitem    item    longeritem    item    longitem    item
longitem    item    longitem    item    longeritem    item    longitem
...
```

How can I get it to print like this?

```
item        longitem    item        longeritem  item        longitem
longitem    item        evenlongeritem          item        longeritem 
item        longitem    item        evenlongeritem          ...
```

I think it's easier seen than said, but I want to divide the page up into columns which start a new item, and if an item is big enough that it stretches past the succeeding column, then the next item will start at the column after that.

Here's my view:

```
<% @model.each do |model| %>
  <%= link_to model.name, model_path(model) %>&nbsp
<% end %>
```

Sample html printout:

```
<div id="Everything">
  <a href="/models/2">LongItem</a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
  <a href="/models/1">LongerItem</a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
  <a href="/models/3">Item</a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
  <a href="/models/4">Item</a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
  <a href="/models/6">LongItem</a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
  <a href="/models/5">Item</a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
  <a href="/models/7">EvenLongerItem</a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: I reckon this is a pure html and css problem. It is not specific to rails in any way (unless you want to know how to generate a html table in rails). I suggest that you change you provide a html code example and adjust the tags.

Comment: @spickermann By html code, do you mean the page source? I posted an example above.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm trying to print into my view.

Comment: BTW: `&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp` - entities always ends with `;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly what you want, but I guess it is much clearer and easier to maintain:

```
<table>
  <% @model.in_groups_of(6) do |group| %>
    <tr>
      <% group.each do |model| %>
        <td><%= link_to(model.name, model_path(model)) %></td>
      <% end >
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: Wouldn't 'model' in the <td></td> line be nil then?

Comment: What makes you think that `model` can be `nil` in this example? If `@model` in your example is a collection, that a `group` is a array of 6 `models`. Have a look what the `in_groups_of` does: http://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of